# Padding not working for divs icons

Tags: html, css, margin, inline, padding

I am trying to add padding to my .slotIcon class. My .slots class is the container, witch is inline-block with another div, trying to make both divs side by side (50% width).

This is all under the "work" section.

Now padding doesn't affect the icons, and margins move the entire .slots div.

All I want to do is slightly lower the icon and text, in the .slots div.

https://jsfiddle.net/js1rgh4b/1/

```
 <div  class="work" >
    <h2>Work</h2>

    <div class="slots">

        <div class="slotIcon"></div>
            <p>Slots</p>
    </div><div class="OEA">

        <div class="OEAicon"></div>
            <p>OEA</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

Css:

```
.slots {
display: inline-block;
width: 50%;
height: 350px;
background-color: #3484ce;
}



.OEA {
display: inline-block;
width: 50%;
height: 350px;
background-color: green;
}

.slotIcon {
width: 150px;
height: 159px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-image: url(http://media.idownloadblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Imgur-1.0-for-iOS-app-icon-small.png);
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}



.OEAicon {
width: 200px;
height: 159px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-image: url(http://media.idownloadblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Imgur-1.0-for-iOS-app-icon-small.png);
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/js1rgh4b/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set padding to `.slots` and `.OEA div` ,this will make the text and the icon come down. And instead of `display: inline-block` , you can use `float:left` to make the div's align side by side.

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/js1rgh4b/2/)**

**CSS:**

```
.slots {
    float:left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 350px;
    background-color: #3484ce;
    padding:60px;
}
.OEA {
    float:left;
    padding:60px;
    width: 50%;
    height: 350px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please Try This,

```
.slots {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    height: 350px;
    background-color: #3484ce;
    padding-top:60px;
}



.OEA {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    height: 350px;
    background-color: green;
    padding-top:60px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you give a `padding` to `.slots`, it works. You would need to do the same for `.OEAicon` if you want them to be similar. If not, then do `vertical-align: top;` in `.OEA`.